# Google Maps API disapears when I try to animate the marker

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I'm trying to put a Google Map API on my website (I'm still pretty new with JavaScript and HTML and what not) and I have got the map on the website no problem, I've even added a marker to a specific location no problem. My problem is when I try to animate the marker. I have even copy and pasted a demo code from the w3-school website and simply changed the co-ordinates and it still doesn't work. Whenever I add in the piece of JavaScript that animates it, the map simply disappears from my page....

```
   function myMap() {
                var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(54.524723, -1.556118);
                var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
                var mapOptions = { center: myCenter, zoom: 5 };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myCenter });
                marker.setMap(map);
```

Above is the code without any form of animation which is fine. Below is the code with the animate and that is what is making my map disappear. Can anyone see any problems at all? any help is greatly appreciated!

```
  function myMap() {
                    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
                    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(54.524723, -1.556118);
                    var mapOptions = { center: myCenter, zoom: 5 };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myCenter,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                    });
                    marker.setMap(map);
                }
```

Comment: Check the browser console. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I've checked it, without the animation code it says there is nothing wrong, by that I mean no errors. With the code, it says myMap is not a function but surely if that was the problem it would flag in the other one as well?

Comment: We don't see enough of your code to find the error. The first function is missing its final `}`, the second is fine syntax-wise.

Comment: Sorry, this is the end of the code:

       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: "Continuous Movement"
                    });
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }

Comment: Create a [mcve] or we cannot help you.